# How to customize references to sublists in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a list/sublist structure in my LaTeX document.  By default, the sublist is delimited with letters, so you end up with this:

```
1. Item
    (a) sub item
    (b) sub item
```

In my document, I've got more than 26 sub items, so I was running into a Counter overflow error, which I fixed by rewriting the sub item label, so that they now look like this

```
1. Item
    1.1 sub item
    1.2 sub item
```

I've put a label on one of the items so that I can reference the specific step later on.  The problem is that when the reference is rendered, it's rendered using a letter, not the number of the sub item.

Here's a sample doc that shows the problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{lbl} Label here
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Ref: \ref{lbl}

\end{document}
```

This gets rendered like this:

```
1. Item
    1.1 Label here
Ref: 1a
```

So instead of saying "Ref: 1.1", it's using "Ref: 1.a".  Is there a way to make the \ref use the numbering of the source enumeration?  If not, is there anyway to generate correct references to items in a sublist with more than 26 items?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm looking at my copy of The LaTeX Companion, p.129, and from what I'm seeing I would suggest something like the following:

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}
\makeatother
```

I don't have access to a working LaTeX environment to test this at the moment, though.

Comment: That did it - I really need to get that book.  Thanks!

Comment: One can also using \usepackage{fncylab}

Answer (score 3):

So for 2 nested lists it should be done in the following way:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.\theenumiii.}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}
\renewcommand{\p@enumiii}{\theenumi.\theenumii.}
\makeatother

...

\end{enumerate}
```

It has taken to me too much time to understand it.
I hope this helps as this thread helped me.

Thanks.